# Is it possible to use Chrome as a transport?

Tags: proxy, http, google-chrome

I am in need to send some json log files to an AWS server.

But the proxy, ISP or something else I cannot get in touch with is blocking everything else besides browsers on 80 and 443. Even Curl and wget are failing.

Is there a way to pipe my data thru Chrome? I mean run my application and have it use Chrome to send the HTTP requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just convince the site your *are* using a browser, e.g. with

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"
```

(User agent string from [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/))

Comment: and an example for curl as you mention it. curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to use an SSH tunnel on port 443. Most firewalls let it pass through, since they cannot read whats inside the encrypted connection anyway and just assume HTTPS. You could then connect via the embedded SOCKS proxy simulated by the tunnel.

Comment: If everything except certain browsers are blocked, the blocking entity can read the HTTPS request and interpret the `user-agent` header. Therefore, this wouldn't help.